# How to get current month in webdriver using java

Tags: java, date, webdriver

I wonder if someone can help!

I've been using following 'Get_Date' class with method 'Get_month' to return the current month but I've now decided to move onto webdriver but am not sure what the webdriver equivalent of following function be.

```
package hisScripts;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;

public class Get_Date {

public String Get_Month(Selenium selenium) {
    return selenium.getEval("var MonthNames =  [ \"Jan 2012\", \"Feb 2012\", \"Mar 2012\", \"Apr 2012\", \"May\", \"Jun\", \"Jul\", \"Aug\", \"Sep\", \"Nov 2011\", \"Nov 2011\", \"Dec 2011\" ];d = new Date();MonthNames[d.getMonth()];");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 public String get_Month(){
   Date date = new Date();
   SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMMMMMM");
   return formatter.format(date);          
 }
```

In case of this month it will return `April`

If you need other notations, refer to [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)